# why does javascript Number function return wrong value for this number?

Tags: javascript, numbers

so I ran into this issue with javascript Number() function, it seems to return the wrong value:
the following code:
 Number("10153396863200835")
   returns 10153396863200836, not 10153396863200835

but if I do  Number("10153396863200836") it returns 10153396863200836
and Number("10153396863200834") returns 10153396863200834

so I'm confused what's going on? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JavaScript's numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (frequently known as "double"). They have only about 15 digits of decimal precision. Your number, `10153396863200835`, is much larger than that.

In doubles, the maximum whole number before we stop being able to represent the next whole number is 9,007,199,254,740,992<sup>1</sup>. 9,007,199,254,740,993 cannot be represented by doubles; 9,007,199,254,740,994 can. That's because at that scale, the least significant bit is worth 2 decimal. The further you go, the bigger those gaps get, as the least significant bit starts being worth 4 decimal, then 8, then...

---

Modern JavaScript has a handy constant for the value right before this value, 9,007,199,254,740,991: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. It's defined as the last whole number in a double where adding 1 gives you the next consequtive whole number. The name is *slightly* misleading, as 9,007,199,254,740,994 or indeed 10,153,396,863,200,836 aren't going to suddenly stop having those values, it's just that math with them starts getting...interesting.

Comment: ok thanks, that explains it very well.